# How to find control based on Name attribute

Tags: c#, .net, windows-7

I am using windows 7 and c# to make an app to control a different GUI app also made by me using c# and .net). In this app I want to get the status of certain controls that are inside the GUI app. I am looking for a method to give me the handle to a control based on it's "Name" attribute. However can't find anything that fits my needs. I have managed to get a list of handles of all controls in the GUI app, but how can I search this list for the control with the right "Name"? I have triend converting the handle to a `Control` object using `Control.FromHandle`, but this doesn't seem to work since it returns `null` for all handles. Any ideas?

Comment: Everything gets a thousand times more difficult when you try to do this across process boundaries.  If this is your app then have a thousand reasons to not do this, or use supported .NET process interop mechanisms like named pipes, sockets, WCF.  If this is not your app then the only reasonable approach is UI Automation, supported by the System.Windows.Automation namespace.

Answer (score -1):

Mb help this?: 
typeof([typeFromYourAssembly]).Assembly.GetTypes().ToList().Single(i=>i.IsSubclassOf(typeof(UserControl)) && i.Name == "[ControlName]")